# Comparing two columns in a matrix in python

Tags: python

I have a file containing following data:

```
PAIR 1MFK 1 URANIUM 82 HELIUM 112 3.6997  
PAIR 2JGH 2 PLUTONIUM 98 POTASSIUM 88 5.3003  
PAIR 345G 3 SODIUM 23 CARBON 14 1.664  
PAIR 4IG5 4 LITHIUM 82 ARGON 99 2.5506
```

Now, I have to find whether column 5th's value is greater than the columns 7th's value or vice versa.
I used:

```
inp = open("filename".'r').read().strip().split('\n')
for line in map(str.split, inp):
    k = line[5]
    m = line[7]
    if k > m:
        print 'loop 1 satisfies'
    elif m > k:
         print 'loop 2 satisfies'
    else:
         print 'loop error'
```

But the problem is I'm getting output like:

```
loop 1 satisfies  
loop 1 satisfies  
loop 1 satisfies  
loop 1 satisfies
```

But in case if 1st line 5th column's value 82 smaller than 7th's value.
I can't understand the reason for this kind of error.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you aren't converting them to numbers first, your data is still string.

```
>>> '82' < '112'
False
>>> 82 < 112
True
```

As an aside note, the items will start counting from 0, so I think you probably meant to compare the 4th and 6th items.

Comment: use k=int(line[4]) not line[5] as lists starts from 0 index not 1.

Comment: @wim Yeah! I wanted to compare 4th and 6th. But how could I be able to convert the strings into int values...

Comment: @abhisek use built-in function int(),  k= int(line[4]) , now k is an integer.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary  but what if i want to append a column(in int) into the above file. what should i do then ? should i need to convert it in string first but also then how to append a whole column ?

Comment: @abhisek you mean you want to write data back to file?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary nop! I ment that I gonna first make the desired columns int and then perform a mathematical calculation and then I want to append the calculated data in the same file creating a new column...

Comment: @abhisek before writing a integer value to a file you should convert it to a string first, it is done using str() function.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are comparing `Strings`, convert them to `integers` first.

```
inp = open("filename",'r').read().strip().split('\n')
for line in map(str.split, inp):
  k = int(line[4]) #lists start at index 0 not 1
  m = int(line[6])
  if k > m: print 'loop 1 satisfies'
  elif m > k: print 'loop 2 satisfies'
  else: print 'loop error'

loop 2 satisfies
loop 1 satisfies
loop 1 satisfies
loop 2 satisfies
```

Comment: Also, unless I'm miscounting, you want to compare line[4] to line[6].  Lists are zero-based

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have addressed your problem of String comparison, but I'd also like to suggest that you use Python's `csv` module to solve your task. The columns in this file are delimited by spaces, and it's much cleaner and memory-efficient to use a `csv.reader` object.

The revised code would look something like:

```
import csv

inp = csv.reader( open("filename", "r"), delimiter=' ')
for line in inp:
    k = int(line[4]) # 5th column == index 4
    m = int(line[6]) # 7th col == index 6
    if k > m:
        print 'loop 1 satisfies'
    elif m > k:
        print 'loop 2 satisfies'
    else:
        print 'loop error'
```

Also note that this solves your string comparing problem, and uses proper zero-based indexing.

Comment: there are no float values on line[6].